# Windows Store Apps - XAML - Scrollviewer - Turn on pixelsnapping for image inside scrollveiwer

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, pixel

I have an 'Image' inside a 'Scrollviewer'. When I zoom in I want to see the true pixel values, what some people refer to as pixel snapping. I don't want my image anti-aliased. I want it to look pixelated. Similar to if you zoomed in using MS Paint.

Is there an option in 'ScrollViewer' or 'Image' to accomplish this?